# CSV Layer in ArcGIS Javascript API not rendering

Tags: javascript, csv, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Here is the javascript as of now. Things to note:

1. This is all running locally on my machine
2. food.csv is located in the same folder as the main HTML file
3. I got the static image from ESRI's developer site.

So far the map runs fine when I load in the browser. However, I have no idea why the CSVLayer is not being rendered. Please help!

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
<script>
var map;
require([
       "esri/map",
       "esri/layers/CSVLayer",
       "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
       "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
       "dojo/domReady!"
       ],
       function(Map, CSVLayer, PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleRenderer) {


           var map = new Map("map", {
              basemap: "gray",
              center: [-.1, 34.75], // longitude, latitude
              zoom: 2
            });

           // CSV Layer created using the fields we want to bring through to the client
           var layer = new CSVLayer("food.csv", {
             fields: [{name: "amount", type: "Number"}]
           });

           var logo = new PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/YellowStickpin.png", 16, 11); // Define a marker image
           var simpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(logo); // Define a new renderer
           layer.setRenderer(simpleRenderer); //Set the simple point renderer to the feature layer

           map.addLayer(layer); // Add the layer to the map


       });


</script>
```

Comment: The [gis.se] Stack Exchange has thousands of questions on the ArcGIS API for JavaScript asked and answered.

Comment: can you post some content of food.csv ?

Answer (score 0):

I never set up the webserver. The code is now running on MAMP and working fine.